# delete all rows until I encounter a non-empty row in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

How do I delete all rows until I encounter a non-empty row in a particular column?

Example: I want to delete the red part. The right table is my desired output.

[image]

If I encounter the word 'Barrier' in column2, I want to delete all rows in front of it up to the row where I encounter a value in Column1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'Barrier' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ].
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'Barrier'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['C',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x']], 
   columns=['column1', 'column2'])
```

Comment: Can't it be solved by just iterating bottom up and if col2 is 'Barrier' then delete row until col1 cell is not None?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only necessary to go through the DF once (starting at the end) marking rows for removal then use the markings to form the new DF. This is much more efficient than repeatedly adding rows to a new DF.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'Barrier' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'Barrier'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['C',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column1', 'column2'])

deleting = False
idx = len(df) -1

while idx >=0:
    if df.loc[idx, 'column2'] == 'Barrier':
        df.loc[idx, 'column2'] = 0
        deleting = True
    elif deleting and df.loc[idx, 'column1'] == None:
        df.loc[idx, 'column2'] = 0
    elif deleting and df.loc[idx, 'column1'] != None:
        df.loc[idx, 'column2'] = 0
        deleting = False
    else:
        deleting = False
    idx -= 1

df2 = df[df['column2'] != 0].reset_index(drop = True)
print(df2)
```

gives:

```
   column1 column2
0        A       x
1     None       x
2     None       x
3        A       x
4     None       x
5     None       x
6     None       x
7        B       x
8     None       x
9     None       x
10    None       x
11       C       x
12    None       x
13    None       x
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply implemented a solution according to [Отгонтөгс Миймаа](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4308431/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d3%a9%d0%b3%d1%81-%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b0)'s suggestion:

> Can't it be solved by just iterating bottom up and if col2 is 'Barrier' then delete row until col1 cell is not None?

```py
def barrier_remover(data):
    reversed_data = []
    is_deleting = False
    for col1, col2 in reversed(data):
        if is_deleting:
            if col1 is None:
                continue
            is_deleting = False
        elif col2 == "Barrier":
            is_deleting = True
            continue
        else:
            reversed_data.append([col1, col2])
    return reversed(reversed_data)
```

And here are the results:

```
>>> data = [
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'Barrier' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    ['A',   'x' ],
    [None,  'x' ],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['B',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'Barrier'],
    [None,  'x'],
    ['C',   'x'],
    [None,  'x'],
    [None,  'x']
]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(barrier_remover(data), columns=['column1', 'column2'])
>>> df2
   column1 column2
0        A       x
1     None       x
2     None       x
3        A       x
4     None       x
5     None       x
6     None       x
7        B       x
8     None       x
9     None       x
10    None       x
11       C       x
12    None       x
13    None       x
```

Comment: Note that `append` has been deprecated in recent versions of Pandas; `concat` can be used instead. However, it would be more efficient to mark rows for removal (eg column2 = 0) and then use a mask to form the new DF in one action.

Comment: @user19077881 is it possible for you or for scr to make a quick implem? My data is 600k rows long so a more efficient way would be appreciated:)

Comment: I don't understand, `data` is not a pandas dataframe, but a list. `append` is absolutely not deprecated on lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try...

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'Barrier'],
    ['A', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    ['A', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    ['B', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    ['B', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'Barrier'],
    [None, 'x'],
    ['C', 'x'],
    [None, 'x'],
    [None, 'x']],
    columns=['column1', 'column2'])

res_data = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['column2'] == "Barrier":
        while res_data[len(res_data) - 1][0] is None:
            res_data.pop()
        res_data.pop()
    else:
        res_data.append([row['column1'], row['column2']])
        
res_df = pd.DataFrame(res_data, columns=['column1', 'column2'])
print(res_df)
```

**Output:**

```
column1 column2
0        A       x
1     None       x
2     None       x
3        A       x
4     None       x
5     None       x
6     None       x
7        B       x
8     None       x
9     None       x
10    None       x
11       C       x
12    None       x
13    None       x
```